# is there any way to change text of a section when user scrolls 100vh down the page without going to next section?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-animations

I was trying a text animation in which when user scrolls down 100vh down the text changes and after that next section comes tried doing this but i just cant find how to pull this.

please help me out here I just cant get how to solve this.

this is the representation of the process I want to do.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uY05.png)

Answer (score 0):

first you will need an event that detects that there was a scroll

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {  
// called when the window is scrolled.  
}
```

within the function you need to know if the scroll has reached the limit you want

```
   var win = window.innerHeight // size of your screen corresponds to 100vh
```

if propert window.scrollY is biger than your win variable, then you do what you want.

```
if(window.scrollY > win){
//do what you want
}
```

at the end shoud look like

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {
let win = window.innerHeight
    // called every time the window is scrolled. 
   if(window.scrollY > win){
    //do what you must
    } 
}
```

Comment: but during that 100vh period how i can prevent it from going down without hindering with the scrolling ?